# How do construct an xpath to select items that do not contain a string

Tags: xpath

How do I use something similar to the example below, but with the opposite result, i.e items that do not contain `(default)` in the text.

```
<test>
     <item>Some text (default)</item>
     <item>Some more text</item>
     <item>Even more text</item>
</test>
```

Given this

```
//test/item[contains(text(), '(default)')]
```

would return the first item. Is there a not operator that I can use with contains?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```
//test/item[not(contains(text(), '(default)'))]
```

Hint: `not()` is a function in XPath instead of an operator.

---

An alternative, possibly better way to express this is:

```
//test/item[not(text()[contains(., '(default)')])]
```

---

There is a subtle but important difference between the two expressions (let's call them A and B, respectively).

**Simple case:** If all `<item>` only have a single text node child, both A and B behave the same.

**Complex case:** If `<item>` can have *multiple* text node children, expression A only matches when `'(default)'` occurs in the first of them.

This is because `text()` matches all text node children and produces a node-set. So far no surprise. Now, `contains()` accepts a node-set as its first argument, but it needs to convert it to string to do its job. And conversion from node-set to string only produces the string value of the first node in the set, all other nodes are disregarded (try `string(//item)` to see what I mean). In the simple case this exactly what happens as well, but the result is not as surprising.

Expression B deals with this by explicitly checking every text node individually instead of only checking the string value of the whole `<item>` element. It's therefore the more robust of the two.